# C++ assigning string variables in if statements

Tags: c++

I am new to C++.  I am trying to assign a string to a month depending on the number chosen in cin.
This is my code within a function.

```
cout << "Enter your birth month: ";   

cin >> mm;   //Birth Month// 

int mm; 

std::string month;

if(mm == 5 || mm == 05){ 
    std::string month = "May"; 
} 
    // If month is equal to 5 or 05, set string variable month to May

cout << "You were born in the month of " << month << endl;
```

How do i assign the variable "month" to "may" if mm is equal to 5?

Comment: Whats your question?

Comment: Sorry if i was a big vague.  Edited

Comment: "I assume..." Why assume and not look it up?

Comment: Well crush.  Today was my first day with this language. I am sorry you were offended by the word.  Props to πάντα ῥεῖ for helping me out.  Apologize for an apparent dumb question due to the immediate down vote on the question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your string variable is actually shadowed by another declaration in the `if` block scope

```
if(mm == 5 || mm == 05) { 
    std::string month = "May"; // That value is gone after the `}`
}
```

You probably want to write

```
if(mm == 5) { 
    month = "May"; // Note the type declaration is omitted here
}
```

---

Also note that why I ommitted `mm == 05` in my sample above, is bacause

```
if(mm == 5 || mm == 05)
```

is wrong. The second comparison expression actually compares with an octal integer literal, and you certainly don't want to do this.

```
if(mm == 5)
```

is sufficient.

Comment: and probably just `if(mm==5)` and move the `int mm` declaration above the `cin`

Comment: Right, he's redeclaring the variable.

Comment: It's not "redundant" in general; here it is only because `5 < 8`.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Ah!! Good point I always forget about those fricking octal literals.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit great catch!

Comment: So it's not actually redundant. It's simply erroneous. It's spelled "octal" btw.

Comment: @crush Forgive a non native speaker please. Ya, now we gerrrrmans like the _hard_ consonants.

Answer (score 1):

You already declared your string above, so a simple assignment operation on month would work:

```
if(mm == 5 || mm == 05){ 
    month = "May"; 
 }
```

Also, even if the user enters "05" as their integer, it will be stored as '5', so there is no need for the condition

```
|| mm == 05
```

Side note, you must declare "int mm" before your cin statement, like this:

```
int mm;
cout << "Enter your birth month: ";   
cin >> mm;   //Birth Month//
```

Comment: Thank you for letting me know that 0 is ignored and it will end up.  also i am not sure why i posted int mm after the cin.  It is at the beginning of the function in my devc.  Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

```
month = "May";
```

This is an assignment.

```
std::string month = "May";
```

This is not an assignment. This us a declaration. You are declaring a new variable called `month`, unrelated to any other variable by the same name you might have.